# Getting Integer object from ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc

A `ResultSet` provides method `getInt()` that returns primitive `int`. Is it possible to obtain the `Integer` object, which permits `null`? The DB field I'm retrieving is nullable and `getInt()` returns me `0` whenever the field is `null`.

Thanks

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Just check if the field is `null` or not using [`ResultSet#getObject()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28java.lang.String%29).

```
Integer foo = resultSet.getObject("foo") != null ? resultSet.getInt("foo") : null;
```

Or, if you can guarantee that you use the right DB column type so that `ResultSet#getObject()` really returns an `Integer` (and thus not `Long`, `Short` or `Byte`), then you can also just typecast it.

```
Integer foo = (Integer) resultSet.getObject("foo");
```

UPDATE: For Java 1.7+

```
Integer foo = resultSet.getObject("foo", Integer.class);
```

Comment: It should be inefficient either, since references to Boolean are cached as long as the constructor isn't used (Boolean.TRUE and FALSE).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it adds boilerplate code. Wish there's a cleaner way.

Comment: What about `Integer foo = (Integer) rs.getObject("foo");`? (or use a try-catch to catch the casting error and set it to null/report error as needed).

Comment: That would only work if the DB column type is mapped to Java `Integer`. See updated answer.

Comment: Be careful with your driver and database. Unfortunately `resultSet.getObject("foo", Integer.class)` returned 0 for me when column was null. `(Integer) resultSet.getObject("foo")` returns null. I've used Oracle driver.

Answer (score 12):

You can check for `wasNull` after retrieving the value.

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29):

> Reports whether the last column read had a value of SQL NULL.
>   Note that you must first call one of the getter methods on a column to try to read its value and then call the method wasNull to see if the value read was SQL NULL.

Comment: It's unfortunately not nicely doable in a single code line.

Answer (score 8):

There is a simpler way., Just type cast it. If null, it will be null. If valid, then it becomes the autoboxed object.

```
(Integer) resultSet.getObject("foo")
```