# Getting Boolean from ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, sql, resultset

ResultSet#getBoolean seems to return false when it's null.
Is there an easy way to get a `Boolean` (not `boolean`) from a `ResultSet`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can call wasNull after calling getBoolean. It's explained here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29

Comment: So I'd have to use: `Boolean foo = result.getBoolean("bar"); if (result.wasNull()) foo = null;`?

Comment: Yes, you can use it like that.

Comment: Thanks, great help

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?serverTimezone=UTC");){

        // create table bool_table (bool_value boolean);
        // insert into bool_table values (null);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM bool_table";

        try (PreparedStatement preStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)){

            try (ResultSet rs = preStmt.executeQuery()) {
                rs.next();

                System.out.println(rs.getObject(1, Boolean.class));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It throws java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Comment: @NadavB, that shouldn't be the case, at least for MySQL. I added a full example.

Comment: it happened to me with postgresql. The second answer with the wasNull worked for me fine. So maybe your answer is only for mySQL?

Comment: @NadavB, yes, as the original question was related to MySQL only.

Comment: This will also return false when the DB column is null, which is what the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: This solution worked very well for me, using AS400/DB2. Thanks Alexey!

Answer (score 5):

You should get the desired result (ie: null when the column value is null) by using `ResultSet.getObject()` and then casting to a `Boolean` Object.

Like this:

```
Boolean someBool = (Boolean) rs.getObject("booleanColumnName");
```

I think this is safe as long as your column type corresponds to boolean (ie: `TINYINT(1)`), But test it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5881851/3684479) does the same thing but with the `Integer` Object.

Comment: `Integer` cannot be casted to `Boolean`.

Comment: You're casting an `Object` to `Boolean`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(int)

Comment: `The type of the Java object will be the default Java object type corresponding to the column's SQL type`. Read about casting.

Comment: In Oracle there is no boolean column, but method getBoolean is working.

Answer (score 4):

```
resultSet.getObject(1) == null ? null : resultSet.getBoolean(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use java optional for that:

```java
    public static Boolean getNullableBoolean(ResultSet rs, String column) throws SQLException {
        return Optional.ofNullable((Boolean)rs.getObject(column))
                       .map(Boolean::booleanValue).orElse(null);
    }
```

...

```java
getNullableBoolean(rs, "my_boolean_column")
```

Comment: This is redundant -- you are converting a Boolean to a boolean with "booleanValue()", then converting it back again by returning it to a boxed Boolean context. Your code is entirely equivalent to doing `return (Boolean)rs.getObject(column)`. HTH!